# Finding "equilibrium"

Tags: calculus, recurrence-relations, nonlinear-system

Say I have three amounts $A$, $B$ and $C$. And a set of conversions between them $K_{A->B}$, $K_{B->A}$ and $K_{B->C}$. The conversions denote what fraction and at what efficiency they convert between the to amounts in the system, so for example we could have:

$A = 100$

$B = 150$

$C = 0$

$K_{A->B}$ converts 0.2 of A to B at an efficiency of 1

$K_{B->A}$ converts 0.1 of B to A at an efficiency of 1.2

$K_{B->C}$ converts 0.3 of B to C at an efficiency of 0.5

Given that the conversions are cyclic like above, what method could I use to find the final value of A, B and C after conversion?

**PS. As I really don't know in which direction to look for a solution to this - I'm not at all proficient at math - please help me tag this question appropriately.**

Comment: I don't understand the significance of "efficiency". Are you saying the first process takes 20% of the amount of A currently present and converts it into the same amount of B? If so, then you are essentially asking for an appropriate solution to $\begin{bmatrix} 0.8 & 0.12 & 0 \\ 0.2 & 0.6 & 0 \\ 0 & 0.15 & 1 \end{bmatrix}x=x$.

Comment: The solution to this problem, as you might guess from physical intuition, is that everything becomes $C$, i.e. all the $A$ eventually becomes $B$ and all the $B$ that appears eventually becomes $C$. That's simply because there is no way to ever lose $C$, and yet everything can become $C$ (possibly in multiple steps).

Comment: @Ian Yes, exactly. And the second process takes 10% of the current amount of B, multiplies it with 1.2 and adds it to A. I'm not sure it is significant to the actual solution, but it is a part of my problem :)

Comment: In that case I have described the solution to your problem. Do you see how I came up with the matrix?

Comment: @Ian Hmm... ok, what if there was no $K_{B->C}?

Comment: The method of solution would be the same, but then there would be a nontrivial equilibrium.

Comment: @Ian when you say non-trivial, can you help point me in the right direction? :) I'm not sure what solution, you are referring to that is.

Comment: The process can be described by a matrix. You keep track of how much of each component is lost at each step, and how much each component contributes to each other component at each step. In your case with all three steps, you get the matrix I wrote above, and you need to find a fixed point (something that gets mapped to itself, so running the process again makes nothing happen). With just two steps you get a smaller matrix, but you still need to find a fixed point. You can do that with Gaussian elimination (also called row reduction).

Comment: @ian thank you! There's a lot there for me to learn. I might be a bit dim here, but I can't figure out how the conversions mapped to your matrix? I'm sorry if I start at too low a level here...

Comment: In a given step, you lose 20% of the A you have, and you get 12% of the B that you have as A. So if we call the new value of $A$ $A'$ then $A'=0.8A+0.12B$. That's the meaning of the first row. Similarly, you lose 40% of the B that you have, and you get 20% of the B that you have as A. So $B'=0.2A+0.6B$. Similar for $C$.

Comment: @ian thank you, this is really helpful!

Comment: @ian I been thinking about your remark, that everything will become $C$ in the original setup. I can see why now, but that is a actually a very unrealistic result given my real world problem. And I can see now, that it is because each step can only ever convert the "same amount" once. So for the first process it's 20% percent of the original amount of $A$, but after that it's only 20% of what ever it has gained since last iteration. Does that make sense?

Comment: That is indeed what I was assuming. You still get that result. To not get that result you need either something that can't become $C$ in any sequence of steps, or a way for $C$ to convert back into something else.